# Getting startAsciiWriting (x, filename, ....) error in R?

Tags: r, elevation, maxent

I am new to R. I am trying to transform elevation data in R for input into MaxEnt. Returned:

> Error in .startAsciiwriting (x,filename ...): x has unequal horizontal
>   and vertical resolutions. Such data cannot be stored arc-ascii format.

Further information as requested:
The following script was run (from https://www.azavea.com/blog/2018/10/09/preparing-data-for-maxent-species-distribution-modeling-using-r/):

```
assign(paste0("elev_", "raw"), raster(“elevation.tif”))
assign(paste0("elev_", "projected"), projectRaster(elev_raw, crs=projection))
assign(paste0("elev_final"), elev_projected)
elev_extended <- extend(elev_final, ext, value=NA)
elev_final_re <- resample(elev_final, elev_final)
elev_tend <- extend(elev_final_re, ext, value=NA)
writeRaster(elev_tend, filename=”elev_output.asc”, format=’ascii’, overwrite=TRUE)
```

---

> Error in .startAsciiwriting (x,filename ...): x has unequal horizontal
>   and vertical resolutions. Such data cannot be stored arc-ascii format.

What does this mean and what can I do about this?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that your code is going sideways in the `projectRaster` function. You do not have the res argument defined so, it is likely that the cell resolution is not the same in the x,y dimensions. Since an ASCII Grid is a numeric array with a descriptive header, a symmetrical cell size is an absolute requirement. To address this just define the res argument with a single number representing the expected cell resolution (in the appropriate projection units).

Please ignore the way that the linked blog is creating objects, unless actually needed, using `assign` is very bad practice. There is absolutely no need to be pasting and assigning object names in this way. You can use "`<-`" or "`=`" to create and assign and object in R eg., `elev_raw <- raster(“elevation.tif”)` I also cannot see any need whatsoever to use `raster::resample` with the same object.

Your code can be reduced thus:

```
elev <- extend(projectRaster(raster("elevation.tif"), 
               res=30, crs=projection), ext, value=NA)
writeRaster(elev, filename="elev_output.asc", overwrite=TRUE)
```

I would recommend setting the "ext" object using the maximum extent of your study area following something like and if possible, using a projected geographic reference system, with distance based projection units (eg., feet, meters), and not a geographic projection, which has its projection units in decimal degrees.